# How can I dress up a tree stump?

Tags: landscaping

We’ve got a tree stump in our yard, an old oak tree that was struck by lightning and partially cut down by the original owners of our house before we moved in. It’s about 4 feet tall. It’s not in the way or anything, so we don’t want to have it removed but it’s an eyesore.  Does anyone have any ideas on how we could make it look a bit better?

Comment: How wide is the stump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to add what’s known as a tree face. The face can be screwed right into the stump and can really help change it into something fun. We added three whimsical style faces on our property, two on actual trees and one on a stump. The grandkids love them. We even got one that looks like an old man. The grandkids call him, “Grandpa Tree.” On the face that’s installed on the tree stump we added a potted plant on the top of it so it looks like he’s got hair. This might help: 
https://www.gardenandpatiohomeguide.com/tree-faces-the-easiest-way-to-add-personality-to-your-yard/

Answer (score 1):

My old silver maple stump had a convenient rotted hole, in which I planted tiger lilies. It looked pretty nice until the stump got soft enough to whack apart with a sledge. Now I have a patch of tiger lilies growing on the remaining tree mulch. 
If your stump lacks a hole you can put dirt and plants in, you can fix that with a hatchet. I suspect flowering vines would also look pretty growing out of the old tree. Whichever, plant roots will speed the natural breakdown of your stump.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have small kids around? Turn it into a fairy stump. 
If it’s in the front yard turn it into a street library

Answer (score 0):

I lived in a rental that had a stump like once but it was starting to rot on the inside.  We knocked out one side, built a retaining wall with bricks and planted overflowing flowers.  It was actually quite nice to look at.